# How do I black out all polygons except one using Geoserver SLD_BODY= parameter in GetMap URL?

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, url

I am trying to use the SLD_BODY= parameter to set a style that will black out all polygons except one; the remaining polygon should be transparent. However, the image comes back with all the polygons blacked out, and the transparent polygon isn't visible because of the black polygons behind it.

This SLD will work if I create the geoserver SLD config file to draw from, but does not work when I pass the SLD through the URL itself. The non-URL encoded version of the SLD is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"     xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld     http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"     xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>blackout_transparent</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>blackout_transparent</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name></se:Name>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>state_abbr</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>KS</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#333333</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Fill>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name></se:Name>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>state_abbr</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>KS</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff2b2f</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0.0</se:SvgParameter>              
        </se:Fill>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
  </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
</NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Is there something wrong with the logic of this SLD or is this possibly a bug with Geoserver?

Comment: Did you leave out "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" before URL-encoding? I guess you did and SLD_BODY was accepted but the result does not look right.

Comment: If you could convert your SLD to work against the "states" demo layer that installs together with Geoserver I can also have a try.

Comment: I did some testing and it does indeed look like a bug in Geoserver. Is it possible for you to place the complete SLD document somewhere in the web and use &SLD= instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question ended up not being an issue of the SLD. The problem was instead and issue with the geometry of the worldwide polygon that was being used to mask the rest of the world except for the states of the US.

The polygons were being stored in PostGIS in WGS84, but when the these polygons were reprojected to Pseudo Mercator, the polygon wasn't being properly projected. The polygons only projected correctly after I pulled the boundaries in a certain amount, I'm thinking to keep it from extending past the northernmost limits of the Pseudo Mercator projection.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any basic problems in your logic, SLD, or GeoServer. I can't test with you layer but here comes a GetMap request that colors Illinois black on the WMS service of Boundless

[&SLD_BODY example](http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&TILED=TRUE&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&FORMAT=image/jpeg&LAYERS=topp:states&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=-125.964082115,14.463954423115467,-65.737188885,59.863747576884535&SLD_BODY=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Csld%3AStyledLayerDescriptor%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fsld%22%20xmlns%3Asld%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fsld%22%20xmlns%3Aogc%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fogc%22%20xmlns%3Agml%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%22%20version%3D%221.0.0%22%3E%0A%3Csld%3ANamedLayer%3E%0A%3Csld%3AName%3Etopp%3Astates%3C%2Fsld%3AName%3E%0A%3Csld%3AUserStyle%3E%0A%3Csld%3AName%3Epopulation%3C%2Fsld%3AName%3E%0A%3Csld%3AIsDefault%3E1%3C%2Fsld%3AIsDefault%3E%0A%3Csld%3AFeatureTypeStyle%3E%0A%3Csld%3AName%3Ename%3C%2Fsld%3AName%3E%0A%3Csld%3ARule%3E%0A%3Csld%3ATitle%3EIllinois%3C%2Fsld%3ATitle%3E%0A%3Cogc%3AFilter%3E%0A%3Cogc%3APropertyIsNotEqualTo%3E%0A%3Cogc%3APropertyName%3ESTATE_NAME%3C%2Fogc%3APropertyName%3E%0A%3Cogc%3ALiteral%3EIllinois%3C%2Fogc%3ALiteral%3E%0A%3C%2Fogc%3APropertyIsNotEqualTo%3E%0A%3C%2Fogc%3AFilter%3E%0A%3Csld%3APolygonSymbolizer%3E%0A%3Csld%3AFill%3E%0A%3Csld%3ACssParameter%20name%3D%22fill%22%3E%234DFF4D%3C%2Fsld%3ACssParameter%3E%0A%3Csld%3ACssParameter%20name%3D%22fill-opacity%22%3E0.7%3C%2Fsld%3ACssParameter%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AFill%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3APolygonSymbolizer%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3ARule%3E%0A%3Csld%3ARule%3E%0A%3Csld%3ATitle%3ENot%20Illinois%3C%2Fsld%3ATitle%3E%0A%3Cogc%3AFilter%3E%0A%3Cogc%3APropertyIsEqualTo%3E%0A%3Cogc%3APropertyName%3ESTATE_NAME%3C%2Fogc%3APropertyName%3E%0A%3Cogc%3ALiteral%3EIllinois%3C%2Fogc%3ALiteral%3E%0A%3C%2Fogc%3APropertyIsEqualTo%3E%0A%3C%2Fogc%3AFilter%3E%0A%3Csld%3APolygonSymbolizer%3E%0A%3Csld%3AFill%3E%0A%3Csld%3ACssParameter%20name%3D%22fill%22%3E%23000000%3C%2Fsld%3ACssParameter%3E%0A%3Csld%3ACssParameter%20name%3D%22fill-opacity%22%3E0.7%3C%2Fsld%3ACssParameter%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AFill%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3APolygonSymbolizer%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3ARule%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AFeatureTypeStyle%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AUserStyle%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3ANamedLayer%3E%0A%3C%2Fsld%3AStyledLayerDescriptor%3E)

You can use the same request for the "states" demo layer on your own Geoserver and the SLD I used looks like this without URL-encoding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
<sld:NamedLayer>
<sld:Name>topp:states</sld:Name>
<sld:UserStyle>
<sld:Name>population</sld:Name>
<sld:IsDefault>1</sld:IsDefault>
<sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
<sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
<sld:Rule>
<sld:Title>Illinois</sld:Title>
<ogc:Filter>
<ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
<ogc:PropertyName>STATE_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
<ogc:Literal>Illinois</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
</ogc:Filter>
<sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
<sld:Fill>
<sld:CssParameter name="fill">#4DFF4D</sld:CssParameter>
<sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.7</sld:CssParameter>
</sld:Fill>
</sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
</sld:Rule>
<sld:Rule>
<sld:Title>Not Illinois</sld:Title>
<ogc:Filter>
<ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
<ogc:PropertyName>STATE_NAME</ogc:PropertyName>
<ogc:Literal>Illinois</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
</ogc:Filter>
<sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
<sld:Fill>
<sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
<sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.7</sld:CssParameter>
</sld:Fill>
</sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
</sld:Rule>
</sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
</sld:UserStyle>
</sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```